# Ray intersection with explicit (1 axis) Bezier triangle?

Tags: bezier-curve

This question asks about how to intersect a ray with a bezier triangle:
[Intersect Ray (Line) vs Quadratic Bezier Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729123/intersect-ray-line-vs-quadratic-bezier-triangle)

What would happen if we had a bezier triangle that had scalars for control points, so they only controlled the height of each point on a triangle?

Would it be much easier then to find where a line intersected it?

Unfortunately I'm not sure where to even start, other than this equation, the explicit quadratic Bezier triangle!  Anyone able to help me out?

$y = P_0S^2+2P_1ST+2P_2SU+P_3T^2+2P_4TU+P_5U^2$

$S,T,U$ are the barycentric coordinates of the triangle and $P_i$ are the scalar control points.

How would I go about finding where a line intersected with such an object, if it did at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier than the general case you asked about before.

You can eliminate $S$, $T$, $U$, and get the equation of the triangular patch in the implicit form $f(x,y,z) = 0$. In fact, the function $f$ will have degree 2, which means that the patch is actually just a portion of a quadric surface. Intersecting a line with a quadric surface is fairly straightforward --- you just have to solve a quadratic equation.